# Help in interpreting glmer and log (odds) as well as plotting my data

Tags: probability, logistic, lme4-nlme, glmm, odds-ratio

the statistical model I had to use for my data turned out way more complicated than I expected. I could really use some help interpreting the results. I am very grateful for any help/advice you have for the following questions:

1. Since it's a binary logistics regression of GLMM can I interpret the results as they are or convert them to some kind of log(odds)/probabilities first? If so how would I do this? (I have tried using the exp() function but since I don't have coefficients as output but fixed effects it doesn´t seem to work?!)
2. If I can interpret them like they are now, how would I do this? Maybe you could give an example (doesn´t have to be on my data, but I am really unsure of the right wording)
3. Also I have been trying to plot the data as a logistic function but could not make it work. It always turned out to be a linear graph. So maybe someone has a suggestion on what I have been doing wrong here?

Here is a part of my R- output :

`````
summary(H2_T2x)
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: Veraenderung_pos ~ ZPA.Mean + (1 | VP)
   Data: Data_T2x

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   208.6    218.0   -101.3    202.6      167 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.1721 -0.4981 -0.3791  0.7435  1.8094 

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 VP     (Intercept) 2.207    1.486   
Number of obs: 170, groups:  VP, 72

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept)  -0.8705     0.2823  -3.083  0.00205 **
ZPA.Mean      0.2541     0.2675   0.950  0.34222   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
         (Intr)
ZPA.Mean -0.078
> Anova(H2_T2x, type=3)
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type III Wald chisquare tests)

Response: Veraenderung_pos
             Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)   
(Intercept) 9.5047  1   0.002049 **
ZPA.Mean    0.9021  1   0.342223   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1


> H3_T2x <- glmer(Veraenderung_pos ~ ZBDI + (1|VP), family = binomial, data = Data_T2x)
> summary(H3_T2x)
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: Veraenderung_pos ~ ZBDI + (1 | VP)
   Data: Data_T2x

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   208.5    217.9   -101.2    202.5      167 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.1792 -0.5055 -0.3977  0.7012  1.9722 

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 VP     (Intercept) 2.101    1.449   
Number of obs: 170, groups:  VP, 72

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept)  -0.8744     0.2781  -3.145  0.00166 **
ZBDI         -0.2897     0.2782  -1.041  0.29774   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
     (Intr)
ZBDI 0.089 
> Anova(H3_T2x, type=3)
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type III Wald chisquare tests)

Response: Veraenderung_pos
             Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)   
(Intercept) 9.8893  1   0.001662 **
ZBDI        1.0843  1   0.297742   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 ````
`````